# Searchbar doesn't work properly in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Currently I am making a search functionality in my project but it isn't working properly. Currently when I typ something in the UISearchbar it does change from search results but its not showing the correct search results. Is this because of the white space between the words in the data? Because when I use single words it does work perfect.

**arrays and dummy data:**

```
var exercises = [exercise]()
    var filteredExercises = [exercise]()

// SOME DUMMY DATA FOR THE TABLEVIEW
        let exercise1 = exercise(exerciseName: "Incline Bench Press")
        let exercise2 = exercise(exerciseName: "Decline Bench Press")
        let exercise3 = exercise(exerciseName: "Bench Press")

        exercises.append(exercise1)
        exercises.append(exercise2)
        exercises.append(exercise3)
```

**Searchbar function:**

```
// ***************** SEARCHBAR FUNCTIONS ************** //
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            inSearchMode = false
            tableView.reloadData()

        }else{

            inSearchMode = true
            let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()


            // each exercise in array is $0 and we taking the name value and the range of the inserted text is that contained in the name
            filteredExercises = exercises.filter({$0.exerciseName.range(of: lower) != nil})
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

**showing in the cell:**

```
// ***************** TABLE DELEGATE FUNCTIONS ******************* //

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exerciseCell", for: indexPath) as? exerciseCell {

//            let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]

            let exer: exercise!

            if inSearchMode {

                print(filteredExercises)
                exer = filteredExercises[indexPath.row]
                cell.updateUI(exercise: exer)
            }else{

                exer = exercises[indexPath.row]
                cell.updateUI(exercise: exer)
            }

//            cell.updateUI(exercise: exercise)
            return cell
        }else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
}
```

Hope someone sees the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying:

```
let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
```

But the `exercises` elements are all titlecased:

```
let exercise1 = exercise(exerciseName: "Incline Bench Press")
let exercise2 = exercise(exerciseName: "Decline Bench Press")
let exercise3 = exercise(exerciseName: "Bench Press")
```

... so `lower` can never match anything in `exercises`.

Comment: omg... im feeling silly now.. So stupid of me hahah

Comment: When I select a row it turns blue and i can select multiple rows but when I am in search and select and go back it will not save that selected row. Do I have to make a new var to store the selected row in search mode?/

Answer (score 0):

You compare lowered and not lowered strings. Change to

```
filteredExercises = exercises.filter({$0.exerciseName.lowercased().range(of: lower) != nil})
```